# Why is my root component in Angular 2 nesting the html?

Tags: angular

I am having the most difficult time getting angular 2 set up for the nth time. So many strange issues come out of the woodwork every step I take, every time I try a new project from scratch to solidify the knowledge.

I currently have the following dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.17",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
```

My index.html is very simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/" ></base>
    <meta charset="utf-8" ></meta>
    <title></title>

    <script src="lib/vendors.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                "app/": { defaultExtension: "js" }
            }
        });

        System.import("app/boot");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
</body>
</html>
```

My boot

```
import { bootstrap } from "angular2/platform/browser";
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from "angular2/router";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

my app.component

```
import { Component } from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "app.html"
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

The app.html is just a `<div>Hello World</div>`

When I run this, the app component nests the entire html tree inside itself. I cannot figure out why.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Update:

It seems that the problem corrects itself if I remove the closing tags from my `<base>` and `<meta>` tags, which were added because angular was throwing complaints at me about them, and by specifying the full path of the app.html templateUrl.

import { Component } from "angular2/core";

```
@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "app/app.html"
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

If I try to use relative url pathing by adding the moduleId: module.id option, it doesn't render anything... even though this works for components that are not the root component. If anyone has insight into why this is in the comments, I would be grateful.

```
@Component({
    selector: "app",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "app/app.html"
})
```

Comment: What happens when you type `http://localhost:<port>/app.html`in the address bar of the browser? Do you get your Hello World div, or do you get the index.html?

Comment: I get index.html, because my server is redirecting all non valid requests back to index.html. The app.html file is in app/app.html and it seems that if I change my templateUrl to be "app/app.html" it works. But if I try to use relative urls by adding moduleId: module.id to the @Component it doesn't work. Nothing loads then.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but you should at least edit your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<base href="/" ></base>
<meta charset="utf-8" ></meta>
```

shouldn't have closing tags. I don't know if this solves your problem, but Angular2 became more pedantic about invalid HTML in beta.

Comment: Well see that's the thing. I added those closing tags because it was throwing errors to me and I found that was the solution to stop it. If I remove them, I start getting errors like this http://i.imgur.com/FXoHL2t.png

Comment: The solution seems to be getting rid of the closing tags, like you mentioned(which I only added because of previous errors), and setting an absolute path to my app.html template (templateUrl: "app/app.html"). Why am I not able to use relative urls with moduleId: module.id within the root component?

Comment: Actually `<base>` allows a closing tag but doesn't require it. The `<meta>` tag must not have a closing tag https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta. Looks like a bug. I wonder why Angular parses the head anyway. I don't use TS (only Dart) and don't know about how to use relative paths with TS.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Where do you get the information that "<base> allows a closing tag"? According to the [official W3C reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element), <base> is a void element with no end tag, just like <meta>.

Comment: @MrLister good question. I remember looking it up, but now all I found sais `base` must not have a closing tag. Thanks for pointing that out!